# ListBox in RowDetail binding failure

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, listbox

I have a WPF application. It contains OrderBlock object which contains other objects, plesase see a brief view of the class.

```
 public class OrderBlocks
 {
     private List<Order> _orders;
    [XmlElement("tF_Transactions")]
    public List<Order> Orders { get { return _orders; } set { _orders = value; OnPropertyChanged("Orders"); } }
 }

 public class Order : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
        [XmlIgnore]
        public List<Duplications> DuplicateHolder { get; set; }  
 }

 public class Duplications
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Duplications(string newID, string newName)
        {
            ID = newID;
            Name = newName;

        }
    }
```

I have a datagrid that is bound to my object Orders of type List Orders. My datagrid has a row detail so that when a user clicks on a row further details are displayed. I have added a listbox to this row detail. I want this row detail to show a listbox which displays my object DuplicateHolder of type List Duplications.

At the moment the listbox is empty. Please see my attempted XAML code below. Any help would be great as always.

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="lbIdentifier" SelectionMode="Single" DataContext="{Binding OrderBlock}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Margin="0,2">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=DuplicateHolder.ID}" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=DuplicateHolder.Name}" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                                                                        
                    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<Listbox ItemSource = {Binding DuplicateHolder}/>
```

and

```
  <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=ID}".../>
```

Comment: Well the listbox is still empty however if I click on the listbox it allows me to select two 'rows' which is the number I am expecting. The font is black so not sure if its just a case that the values are hidden?

Comment: Its now showing. I just changed the Text={Binding Path=DuplicateHolder.ID} to Text={Binding Path=ID} and now its working. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

t seems like you did not set the bindings correctly because the listbox Context should be a list of Duplications and the ItemTemplate should be for one Duplication instance from the list of duplicates. So if the global datacontext is an instance of OrderBlocks the listbox will be bound to the DuplicateHolder of an Order:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Name="lbIdentifier" SelectionMode="Single" DataContext="{Binding Path=DuplicateHolder}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="0,2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=ID}" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" FontSize="10" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>                                                                                        
                </ListBox>
```